# Installing Python-For-Android Linux Ubuntu, Build Errors

Tags: android, linux, installation, kivy

I trying to build a test project just to see if the installation works but I get this error almost instantly.....

/home/kivy/Android/sdk/platform-tools/tools/android

I have installed Android Studio and ran updates.  I installed the 14(android 4.0) tools needed.  I downloaded the NDK and even though Android Studio created a new Android folder with folders like tools, platform, platform-tools, etc I still downloaded the standalone folder Android-Linux (r24.4.1).

Android-Linux and the NDK are sitting at home/documents/sdk_ndk/...

The Android folder created by Android Studio is sitting at home/Android

Android Studio itself is with the NDK and Android-Linux folders.

.bashrc has...

```
            export ANDROIDSDK=$HOME/Documents/sdk_ndk/android-sdk-r24.4.1
            export ANDROIDNDK=$HOME/Documents/sdk_ndk/android-ndk-r13b
            export ANDROIDAPI="14"
            export ANDROIDNDKVER="r13b"
```

I've even tried....

```
            export ANDROIDSDK=$HOME/Android/sdk
            export ANDROIDNDK=$HOME/Documents/sdk_ndk/android-ndk-r13b
            export ANDROIDAPI="14"
            export ANDROIDNDKVER="r13b"
```

Build commands are....

```
            p4a apk --private ~/Desktop/testapp --package=org.example.myapp --name "testapp" --version 0.1 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python2,kivy
```

When I set this...

```
            export ANDROIDSDK=$HOME/Documents/sdk_ndk/android-sdk-r24.4.1
```

Api target 14 is not found.

When I set this...

export ANDROIDSDK=$HOME/Android/sdk

I don't get an api error but I get the path error.

```
            not found   /home/kivy/Android/sdk/platform-tools/tools/android
```

I've even tried...

```
            export ANDROIDSDK=$HOME/Android/sdk/tools
            export ANDROIDSDK=$HOME/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

-------Update-------------------

I've added the '"' around paths.....

```
            export ANDROIDSDK="$Home/Documents/sdk_ndk/android-sdk-r24.4.1"
            #export ANDROIDSDK="$Home/Android/sdk"
            export ANDROIDNDK="$Home/Documents/sdk_ndk/android-ndk-r13b"
            export ANDROIDAPI="14"
            export ANDROIDNDKVER="r13b"
```

And now get and error saying it cant find /tools/android.  This is strange because there is an Android file in the tools folder.  It doesn't have the .sh extension, but it's there.

Here's the whole terminal output......

```
            kivy@kivy-VirtualBox:~$ p4a apk --private ~/Desktop/testapp --package=org.urchatty.com --name "testapp" --version 0.1 --bootstrap=sd12 --requirements=python2,kivy
            [INFO]:    This python-for-android revamp is an experimental alpha release!
            [INFO]:    It should work (mostly), but you may experience missing features or bugs.
            [INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi
            [INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/usr/local/bin/p4a", line 9, in <module>
                load_entry_point('python-for-android==0.4', 'console_scripts', 'p4a')()
              File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 754, in main
                ToolchainCL()
              File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 343, in __init__
                getattr(self, command_method_name)(unknown)
              File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 87, in wrapper_func
                user_ndk_ver=self.ndk_version)
              File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 226, in prepare_build_environment
                android = sh.Command(join(sdk_dir, 'tools', 'android'))
              File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1029, in __init__
                raise CommandNotFound(path)
            sh.CommandNotFound: /Documents/sdk_ndk/android-sdk-r24.4.1/tools/android
            kivy@kivy-VirtualBox:~$
```

---------Update-------------------------

Seems like my paths in the bashrc had to be written as....  "/home/kivy/....".  I didn't get far before another error hit me....

```
            kivy@kivy-VirtualBox:~$ p4a apk --private $HOME/code/myapp --package=org.example.myapp --name "My application" --version 0.1 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python2,kivy
            [INFO]:    This python-for-android revamp is an experimental alpha release!
            [INFO]:    It should work (mostly), but you may experience missing features or bugs.
            [INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi
            [INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
            [INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (4, 19)
            [INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available, continuing.
            [INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
            [INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
            [INFO]:    Using Google NDK r13b
            [INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
            [WARNING]: ndk_platform doesn't exist: /home.kivy/Documents/android-ndk-r13b/platforms/android-19/arch-arm
            [WARNING]: Could not find toolchain subdirectory!
            [WARNING]: Could not find any toolchain for arm-linux-androideabi!
            [WARNING]: Missing executable: autoconf is not installed
            [WARNING]: Missing executable: automake is not installed
            [WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
            [ERROR]:   python-for-android cannot continue; aborting
            kivy@kivy-VirtualBox:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

EL3PHANTEN's answer made the difference.

```
           # $ANDROIDSDK/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --filter 2,3,15
```

Using the terminal instead of the Manager seemed to help.  The files downloaded for the SDK were actually less.  They were much larger using the SDK Manager UI.

The other trick was in the bashrc.  Paths had to start with "/" only.

```
           "/home/kivy/Documents/...."
```

Finally, p4a is doing it's thing.  The Kivy Website really should update it's Docs to include what EL3PHANTEN purposed.  Also, the path styles used in the documents...

```
           export ANDROIDSDK="$HOME/Documents/android-sdk-21"
           export ANDROIDNDK="$HOME/Documents/android-ndk-r10e"
           export ANDROIDAPI="14"  # Minimum API version your application require
           export ANDROIDNDKVER="r10e"  # Version of the NDK you installed
```

That doesn't cut if for some reason.  I could have save myself a lot of bandwidth and time if I would have gotten help from EL3PHANTEN earlier instead of doing everything on the Kivy Website as is.

The only thing on my mind now is, what error will I run into next?  Obviously the Docs on this stuff isn't 100 percent.

Answer (score 0):

As your error says, it cannot find `android` which should be in your `sdk/tools` folder. So eiter your `ANDROIDSDK` variable is wrong, or your `tools` folder does not contain `android`

If its the path variable, check the path of your sdk.
If your `android` executable is missing, try following steps when updating the sdk.

You probably updated everything, without choosing packages.
That means your `tools` folder might be empty now.
What you can do now, is to eiter find the packed `tools` folder in `/home/kivy/Android/sdk/platform-tools/temp`, or delete the whole `sdk` folder and try again.
The correct way to update the `android-sdk` is this:

(the following procedure takes less time, since you dont need all the packages)

First download and unpack the sdk.

Since we dont need all the packages, we first want a list of available packages.

```
# ANDROIDSDK="$HOME/Android/sdk"
# $ANDROIDSDK/tools/android list sdk
```

Now we get a list of packages.
We need to install the build_tools and the platform_tools, which in my case show as 2 and 3. Also we need `SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15` since we chose API version 15. This package is incidentally also shown as 15 in my case. (or whatever API you want)

So we add the filter 2,3,15.

Be sure NOT to install `Android SDK Tools` which is shown as 1 in my case. This will empty the tools folder, and we dont want that.

Note

Your filter might be different, then explained above.

Then run this command to install the packages you chose:

```
# $ANDROIDSDK/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --filter 2,3,15
```

Comment: Actually my tools folder isn't empty.  It has a bunch of files in it, including the manager.

Comment: My android SDK Tools is 24.4.1.  I have android platform tools 25.0.1, build tools 25.0.1, 21, 20 and 19.  I uninstalled all the apis and now I'm downloading API 15 (4.0.3).  Unless there's some specific combination or something else I'm missing, I don't understand the error being raised in my original post.

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1029, in __init__
                raise CommandNotFound(path)
            sh.CommandNotFound:

Comment: @chitondihk yea that means that it cannot find `/Documents/sdk_ndk/android-sdk-r24.4.1/tools/android` That is why I tought your tools folder was empty. Then you might want to check your `ANDROIDSDK=$HOME/Documents/sdk_ndk/android-sdk-r24.4.1` variable. Is that the right folder -> `sdk_ndk`?

Comment: @chitondihk out of curiosity. Which OS are you on since you use VM?

Comment: Win7 64 bit.  I changed my bashrc path style to: "/home/kivy/documents..." and it moved but didn't get far before any other error.  See original post for udate.

Comment: @chitondihk now its the ANDROIDNDK variable :)